# RPG/DB2 Cursor as a resultset being cleared

Tags: db2, rpg

I have an RPG program/stored procedure that returns a resultset to a .net program. Everything is working fine until the RPG is added some code after

```
... RETURN to CLIENT CURSOR C1...

// New Line Of code
... DELETE FROM <FILE>...
```

Why is the resultset empty when it is deleted from the FILE?  Shouldnt the resultset already be in the cursor C1?

What I am trying to do is call a RPG stored procedure and have the procedure return me a resultset from a FILE then delete the records int the file. I thought by setting it to a resulset it would retain the data after I delete the actuall data in the db. but it looks like if I delete the records the resultset is cleared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the chosen records in a temp table, delete them from the original file, then return a result set of the temp table.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing. Is that the perferred option?

Comment: It seems like a solid solution, and there is some merit in simplicity, but I guess we will see if anyone thinks they have a better solution on DB2 for i.